# Signalmaster on https: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, ember.js, socket.io, signalmaster

I have an ember project using Signalmaster. In the config/environment.js I have the following:

```
if (environment === 'production') {

ENV.SIGNALMASTER = {
  HOST: 'https://localhost:8890',
  PORT: '8890',
  FORCE_CONNECTION: true
};
```

On my server I have signalmaster running at https://localhost:8890 (in the development.json and production.json files in the config directory for signalmaster I have secure set to true, and in the server.js file for signalmaster I've put in the location of my SSL certificate and key, as is required for running it on https) - when running "node server.js" I get the following:

```
signal master is running at: https://localhost:8890
```

Running "netstat -lnp" also shows a process running on port 8890. However when I use the app I get errors like this:

```
GET https://localhost:8890/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LjG8--J net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I am using socket.io version 1.3.7.

Comment: I'm using a PositiveSSL Certificate comodo gave me. If I go to [myserverIP]:8890 it says "didn’t send any data" (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) (I don't know if anything is supposed to come up if you go to the port where signalmaster is running - if I go to localhost:8888 where signal master is running in my local environment there's no page)

Comment: This might help https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/issues/307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having the host as https://localhost:8890, seems it had to be https://[domain.com]:8890